# Windows Phone display formatted text using binding in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a textblock which binds to a string from a datasource. The string, however, is html formatted (it has `<p>` and `<a href>` tags).

I want to be able to display the formatted string using binding, so I don't want to manipulate it in code outside of converters. Is there a way to do this with a `RichTextBox`, or some other control?

Answer (score 2):

Try `HTMLTextBox` from the [MSP Toolkit](http://msptoolkit.codeplex.com/), it works quite well for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could host a `WebBrowser` control and display the HTML with the `NavigateToString` method.
If you want to use MVVM and data binding, here is an attached property I created for exactly the same use case.

```
  public static class WebBrowserExtensions
  {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Html",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(WebBrowserExtensions),
      new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHtmlChanged));

    public static void SetHtml(WebBrowser webBrowser, string html)
    {
      webBrowser.SetValue(HtmlProperty, html);
    }

    public static string GetHtml(WebBrowser webBrowser)
    {
      return (string)webBrowser.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
    }

    private static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
      if (webBrowser != null)
      {
        var body = GetHtml(webBrowser);
        var style = "<style>";
        var background = "white";
        var foreground = "black";
        style += "body{background-color: " + background + "; color: " + foreground + ";}";
        style += "</style>";
        var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" + style + "</head><body>" + body + "</body></html>";
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
      }
    }
 }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
  <phone:WebBrowser
   local:WebBrowserExtensions.Html="{Binding Path=Text}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It appears that the OnHtmlChanged method is getting the right format, but I do not see anything on the actual WebBrowser. Am I missing something on the WebBrowser to get it to display?

Comment: My mistake, it was something else. This seems to work perfect!